# Read array from YML in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

I have an array in YML localization file:

```
en:
  difficulty:
    0: "Difficulty"
    1: "Beginner"
    2: "Intermediate"
    3: "Advanced"
```

How can I read values from this array in view template? For example I can get 1 or 2 from db and I want to get values for 1(Beginner) or 2(Intermediate) in erb file and show it to user.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails and Erb:

```
<%= t('difficulty')[1] %>
```

Would produce

```
Beginner
```

So replace '1' with the value from your database. You'd probably set this as an instance variable in your controller (ex. `@difficulty = 1` or `@difficulty = current_user.difficulty`).

Note thought that you've created a `Hash`, not an `Array`. But since you used integer keys, the method for accessing them is identical. An array in YML is represented as:

```
en:
  difficulty:
    - Difficulty
    - Beginner
    - Intermediate
    - Advanced
```

Note that you may want to rewrite this as:

```
en:
  difficulty:
    -
    - Beginner
    - Intermediate
    - Advanced
```

Since it seems like you don't intend to use a difficulty of 0.